# Missing AFHTTPClient.h and other Vendor/AFNetworking files from Restkit git pull

Tags: xcode, git, restkit

After leaving my IOS/Restkit project for a few months and after an XCode update to 4.6 I had a number of link errors. I pulled down the update to Restkit v0.10.x (from XCode Source Control/Pull). After further configuring as per github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x and a clean/build I get a missing AFHTTPClient.h.

Looking in Vendor/AFNetworking there's nothing but red files which seem to be empty.

libRestKit.a chosen as a library for IOS for ResKit is also red.

I'm not a Git expert.

Should I uninstall/delete and reinstall Restkit from the Git source?

Or is there some reason I'm not pulling down those files?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using RestKit v0.10 or v0.20? Because AFHTTPClient is part of the v0.20 version.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I looked at the version file which seems to have been created on my update Feb 9th of the version v0.10 (created in June of 2012) and it shows me 0.20.0-rc1 so presumably my update of the v0.10 project through XCode/Git pulled down v020.

Comment: v020 is still beta. I'll download a new v0.10 and re-install. Thanks.

Comment: RestKit v0.20 is currently available as a RC1, so perhaps you should better start with the new version because a lot of things changed between v0.10 and v.20. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

As flashfabrixx pointed out I've pulled v0.20 rather than v0.10 in my attempt to update v0.10 (v010 doesn't seem to be available anymore). So since I couldn't find my old v0.10 download I'm installing v0.20.